# I need to perform a "ORDER BY", but Azure says it is not supported

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Below is my sample:

SELECT f.id as family, c.FirstName AS child, p.GivenName AS pet 
                    FROM Families f 
                    JOIN c IN f.Children 
                    JOIN p IN c.Pets 
                    WHERE p.GivenName = 'Fluffy'
                 ***ORDER BY c.FirstName***

Comment: can you post your JSON

Comment: Hi @Sajeetharan, here is:  
  [{
   "id": "AndersenFamily",
   "lastName": "Andersen",
   "parents": [{
     "firstName": "Thomas"
    },
    {
     "firstName": "Mary Kay"
    }
   ],
   "children": [{
    "firstName": "Henriette Thaulow",
    "gender": "female",
    "grade": 5,
    "pets": [{
     "givenName": "Fluffy"
    }]
   }],
   "address": {
    "state": "WA",
    "county": "King",
    "city": "Seattle"
   },
   "creationDate": 1431620472,
   "isRegistered": true
  }]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Order-by over correlated collections is not supported" which means that **JOIN** and Order by clause are **`not supported`** together.

You need to consider changing the data model suits your need.